# Yii generates error "Unable to resolve the request <controller/action>"

Tags: yii

After logged in successfully, Yii does not executing any page.

Showing an error:

> Error 404 Unable to resolve the request "membersdet/index"

Here `membersdet` is controller Id and `index` is an action.

Comment: need more information, Harpreet. What did you name the controller class and controller class file? Where did you store them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure the filename of your controller is **EXACTLY** "MembersdetController.php". **It is case sensitive.**

I guess you were developing on local machine under Windows OS and server runs on *nix system. That's normal issue for novice developers, that they forget about case sensitive file system in *nix.

Comment: is there a plugin in yii or a code that i can use so that i dont have to rename every single controller action and page ?

Comment: Old answer, but it got me here ... Also note that you should not use CamelCase, so MyProfileController.php is wrong, while MyprofileController.php is correct.

Answer (score 4):

It is because of wrong controller file name given or may be `actionIndex()` method is not in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Check case sensitive exactly your controller: MembersdetController

Check alias (common in config/main.php) map with namespace in your controller

```
Yii::setAlias('@tienn2t', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/tienn2t');
```

In MembersdetController.php file

```
<?php
namespace tienn2t\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class MembersdetController extends Controller{
    public function actionIndex(){
        echo 1;die;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem and got it solved. In this case the file was correctly named but the class name was wrongly spelled. When these two do not correspond, you could get this error too.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in the question, but maybe you have an incorrect .htaccess or if you don't have an htaccess at all you should use the url:

```
http://host/index.php?r=membersdet/index
```

Comment: I have run this project successfully in localhost. but this creating problem in live server.  I am getting error at this place - CWebApplication->runController('membersdet/index')

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have MembersdetController in /protected/controllers/ and this class "is a" CController and has a public method named actionIndex().

Answer (score 0):

Check errorHandler block in your config file.
I had fix this error like this

```
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'error/index',
],
```

By the way you should have appropriate ErrorController in your module and /error/index.php 
 file in view folder. 
Hope will help you.